# AutoLayout not working after CGRectOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uilabel

I have a UIView called `containerView`.

I add this as a subview to a controller view's root view. I have programmatically added a few constraints to it (I centered it and made the width a few points from the superview's width).

I have added a few `UILabel`s to the `containerView` as subviews. The height of the `UILabel`s dictate the height of the `containerView`.

When the user taps the screen, the `containerView` is moved up from `CGRectOffset()` and once the animation is complete, it is moved back to the original position.

```
CGPoint absolutePoint = self.containterView.frame.origin;
self.containerYConstraint.constant = -absolutePoint;
[UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.5
     animations:^
     {
         [viewForUpdate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.containerYConstraint.constant = 0;
         [viewForUpdate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
         [self.containerView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; // Remove all subviews
     }];
```

I need to remove the `UILabel`s I have put in there as subviews and replace them with different labels. However, the moment I remove one of the UILabel's the entire `containerView` goes missing (I set the background as red so I can see it). I remove all the subviews in the example but when I try to just remove one the same effect occurs.

Why does this occur? Does this have something to do with auto layout? Also if I want to recenter it after I remove one of the UILabels, how do I re-do the constraints?

Comment: Check if container constraints are properly set

Answer (score 1):

Modifying frames when using AutoLayout is a no-no. Once you begin using AutoLayout you're effectively telling the system that you want it to set the frames for you.

Instead of animating the frame directly, create properties pointing to your constraints and animate those constraints.

Comment: I made a property for one of the constraints I use to center the Y axis of `containterView` relative to its parent view. I change the constant instead of using CGRectOffset, and the animation is correct. However, the issue is still there. The `containerView` disappears once I remove a subview.

Comment: Is the container view's height being set based on all labels or just one label? And if it's the latter, are you removing that one label that's being used to set the height? Have you tried setting the height explicitly for testing purposes and then removing the labels to see if it disappears; if it doesn't, you know the disappearance is based on the constraints on the labels as opposed to something else.